# My microphone do not work

Tags: sound, microphone, 17.04

I have Ubuntu 17.04,  early I was truing Linux xfce, but my microphone do not work, at all! I am use "Pulse Audio Volume Control" - rezult is zero.  My inner microphone work with Windows 10. My laptop is ASUS E502S. Anybody help me please. I need to  Skype conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the software center for driver updates?

First update your system software:

Open up a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You'll have to type in your password. Then you may have to type a 'y' to confirm some downloads.

After Ubuntu is updated check the software system for "additional drivers." Type the following command to open the tab in the software center.

```
software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4
```

Check this area to see if there is an update available for your audio drivers.

Comment: I did it, I have this result. What next ?  http://spacelore.dp.ua/images/Screenshot%20from%202017-05-09%2013-36-10.png

Comment: 1- Have you selected the correct input settings?
 Here are some screen shots https://www.onlinemictest.com/microphone-settings/ubuntu/

Comment: 2- I'd update the ALSA drivers. This link has more info. However, I don't see an updated package for 17.0 The latest appears to be for 16.10 https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS